# SugarORM findWithQuery and WHERE IN

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I'm working on an android app that uses sugarORM. I want to get a multiple items that match the ids in a list.

However when i call

```
findWithQuery(A.class, "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> in (?)", "1,2,3")
```

I always get an empty list(although I double checked the query with SQLite DB Browser and it worked).

Splitting this query into multiple findById seems inefficient. Any thoughts on getting WHERE IN to work using SugarORM?

Comment: I wonder if your current query results in `in ('1,2,3')`, whereas you really want `in ('1','2','3')`. Have you tried changing the arguments from `"1,2,3"` to `new String[] { "1","2","3" }` (or just `"1","2","3"`, since the method appears to accepts varargs).

Comment: Those values are integers and not text, so they should not be placed in quotes. Tried it none the less, and still 0 results.

Comment: Although you seem to have found a solution/workaround already, I just wanted to double check that you did also add 3 placeholders when trying my suggestion? So something like: `findWithQuery(A.class, "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> in (?,?,?)", new String[] { "1","2","3" })`. SQLite only takes strings as arguments, but supplying the integer ids as such will not affect the outcome.

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it works. The problem is the number of ids is variable. That means that I would have to build both the whereClause (generate a "? , … , ?"), and then build the String[] whereArgs. That's an extra step that I could live without. But thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more attempts I found that there is a problem with replacing the placeholders.

Switching from:

```
findWithQuery(A.class, "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> in (?)", "1,2,3")
```

To:

```
findWithQuery(A.class, "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> in (1,2,3)", null)
```

fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that SQLite escapes the arguments `"1,2,3"` and turns it into a single value that is then used to replace the single `?` placeholder in your query string. The correct way to supply multiple arguments would be to have a placeholder for every individual argument. Your original line of code would then have to change to:

```
findWithQuery(A.class, "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> in (?,?,?)", new String[] { "1","2","3" })
```

---

You later pointed out that the number of arguments is dynamic. This you can easily be accomplished by generating the query (the where clause in particular) at runtime based on the arguments that you want to query for.

For the most general case, it only takes a few lines of code to do so:

```
final String[] args = new String[] { /* ... */ };
final String query = "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> in " +
    "(" + TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(args.length, "?")) + ")";
final List<A> result = A.findWithQuery(A.class, query, args);
```

(note that you could take a shortcut and inject the arguments directly into the query string - instead of using placeholders - but then you'll loose SQLite's built-in escaping, so I decided against that)

All that's left to do is to generate a `String[]` out of your arguments. A simple helper method like this should cover most scenarios:

```
static String[] toStringArray(Object... args) {
    final String[] array = new String[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) array[i] = args[i].toString();
    return array;
}
```

You'll probably want to add some `null` checks in there and potentially set up a few overloads if you plan on using primitive arrays as arguments.

Disclaimer: I typed everything straight into the browser, so no guarantees that everything works and the first try. :)